# Row Index where one column has a non-zero entry

Tags: r, indexing, row

I think this might be a repeated question but I can't find the answer so here it goes. If I have a matrix X:

```
 > X
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
  [1,]   1    4   55    1    8
  [2,]  48    2    0    1    2
  [3,]  67   23   53   55   78
  [4,]   0   78    0    0    0
  [5,]  85   91   23   65   83
```

What is the easiest way to get the row index where one entry is non-zero and all others are zero? I have tried:

```
test <- which(X[,2] != 0 & X[,-2] == 0)
```

And ideally I would like the result to be: 4. But, that's not what happens... I get that `which()` gives me the index (row and column) so it's probably not the way to solve this... Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
X <- as.matrix(read.table(text="
 1    4   55    1    8
48    2    0    1    2
67   23   53   55   78
 0   78    0    0    0
85   91   23   65   83"))

which(rowSums(X!=0)==1)
# [1] 4
```

Here are 2 ways to correct your approach, note they focus on observing column 2 while my solution doesn't:

```
which(X[,2] != 0 & rowSums(X[,-2] != 0)==0) # [1] 4
which(X[,2] & !apply(X[,-2],1,any,0))       # [1] 4
```

Your approach fails because `X[,-2] == 0` is a matrix of booleans, not a vector as you'd want it to be.

If you want to do this for your all columns separately you can use `lapply` :

```
lapply(seq(ncol(X)),function(i) which(X[,i] != 0 & rowSums(X[,-i] != 0)==0))
```

Comment: This works for this particular example. However, my real problem is more tricky because I have a large matrix (2GB) with many rows and 19 columns and I want to find how many rows have a non zero entry for the first column and zero entries for all the remaining columns... And then do the same for all the other 18 columns. But thanks for the input!

Comment: Check my update on correcting your approach, and take the first one (with rowSums) as it will be faster. replacing `2` by `1`

Comment: try this: `lapply(seq(ncol(X)),function(i) which(X[,i] != 0 & rowSums(X[,-i] != 0)==0))`. If this doesn't give the output you want please update your question, it's not a hard problem to solve but I'm not sure which output format you want.

Comment: That last solution using  `lapply` works perfectly! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try this easy example code:

```
    m<-as.matrix(cbind(a=c(1,1,1,0,0,1),b=c(1,1,1,1,0,0),c=c(1,1,1,0,0,0)))
> m
     a b c
[1,] 1 1 1
[2,] 1 1 1
[3,] 1 1 1
[4,] 0 1 0
[5,] 0 0 0
[6,] 1 0 0
> 
> #Row detection
> which(rowSums(m!=0)==1)
[1] 4 6
> 
> #Column with elemnte !=0
> apply(m[which(rowSums(m!=0)==1),],1,which.max)
[1] 2 1
```

Comment: As mentioned, this works for this particular example. However, my real problem is more tricky because I have a large matrix (2GB) with many rows and 19 columns and I want to find how many rows have a non zero entry for the first column and zero entries for all the remaining columns... And then do the same for all the other 18 columns. But thanks for the input!